# Math.random is returning the same number once applied to a var

Tags: javascript

`Math.random` seems to be working fine in the console. Even when I apply `Math.floor` to it, there is no issue. However, as soon as I assign a `var` to the code. I just get the same number returned.
Example of what I have written:

> Math.random();
> <0.2650735060984091

> Math.random();
> <0.23735521448696772

> Math.random();
> <0.690841980599159

> Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
> <8

> Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
> <7

> Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
> <1

> var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

<undefined

> x;
> <4

> x
> <4

> x
> <4

> x
> <4

The output is constantly 4 when I assign any `var`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: that's how variables work. You're basically doing `var x = 5`, where 5 is the result of the Math statements as example

Comment: You're setting x once, then never again. This is how all programming languages work. If you want to get a new value each time, you need to use a function instead of a variable; that way `Math.random()` is actually called more than once. To clarify, it's like telling a person to pick a number, then asking them which number they picked multiple times. They will tell you the same number each time, obviously.

Comment: `var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);` this line is executed once. Put it into a loop and console it inside the loop. You can find the difference.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is storing the value of `Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);` in `x`. It is not calling `Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);` everytime you are using x. It is the same value. To achieve this you need to have a function so that you can call `Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);` everytime.

```js
function randomFloor() {
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
}

console.log(randomFloor() < 4)
console.log(randomFloor() < 4)
console.log(randomFloor() < 4)
console.log(randomFloor() < 4)
console.log(randomFloor() < 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

By assigning something to a variable, the JavaScript interpreter has to evaluate the expression on the right.

So JavaScript calculates the result of the expression `Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)` **once** and puts it into the variable `x`. The variable now holds this value. When you type `x` into the console, you always get this value at time of assignment. That's the concept of variables (reusing values).

If you want different values in `x`, you need to assign a new value (e.g. by calling `x = Math.floor(...)` again.

If you need a encapsulation of your logic that you can re-use, you can define a function:

```js
function getMyRandomValue() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
}
```

In the console, type `getMyRandomValue()` repeatedly.

You can assign the result to a variable, e.g. `var y = getMyRandomValue()` but then again, the variable `y` gets the value returned by the function call assigned and then holds that value.

P.S: I recommend you to grab a good introductory book to programming. You should get these basics right :-)